# Proving the continuity of a function with respect to a measure

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Let $\mathcal{M}([0,1])$ be the space of all real finite measures on $[0,1]$, with norm $\|\mu\|=|\mu|([0,1])$ and consider the function $$u(y)=\int_{[0,1]}\min\{x,y\}\mu(dx)$$ for $y\in[0,1]$.

I want to prove that it's continuous. So far, I have $$u(y)=x\int_{[0,x]}\mu(dy)+\int_{(x,1]}y\mu(dy)$$

My immediate question would be: how do I evaluate these integrals? But of course, I'd like to know how to answer this question in general.

Comment: Your formula for $u(y)$ is incorrect. It should be
$$
u(y)=\int_{[0,y]}x\,\mu(dx)+\int_{(y,1]}y\,\mu(dx)=\int_{[0,y]}x\,\mu(dx)+y\,\mu((y,1]).
$$

Comment: I think that continuity does not hold if $μ$ is a point measure. For example if it is the unit Dirac measure centered at $x=1/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $U_y(x)=\min(x,y)$.  In $[0,1]$ the $U_y(x)$'s are bounded by $1$ and are continuous functions of $x,y$.  The integral of $1$ in $[0,1]$ is bounded because $\mu$ is a finite measure.  For a given $y_0$ let $y_n$ be any sequence in $[0,1]$ such that $y_n \to y_0$. By continuity $U_{y_n}(x)\to U_{y_0}(x)$ for each $x$.  Apply the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem (1.34 in Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis*) to get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[0,1]} U_{y_n}(x)\, d\mu(x) \to \int_{[0,1]} U_{y_0}(x) \, d\mu(x).$$

Because the choice of sequence $y_n$ was arbitrary, this establishes the desired continuity in $y$.  Just in case, for a unit Dirac measure at $1/2$, $u(y)=y$ for $y<1/2$ and $u(y)=1/2$ for $y>1/2$; note the integral decomposition suggested by Julián Aguirre.